# how to use image in for loop in Twig?

Tags: php, twig, twig-extension

i have the address of images in the array and i want to load 3 image from that source

my code :

```
 {% for address in image.address %}
  <img src="??">

  {% endfor %}"
```

what should I write in the Src in img tag?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally its better to do this :

> ```
> <img src="{{ asset(news.address[i]) }}">
> ```

and we the array are sth like this :

> $news = array(
>                      'address'=>array('bundles/Hippomain/frontend/img/img1.jpg',),
>           );

and in this way we can load each image we have in the array easily !

Answer (score 3):

Simply

```
{% for address in image.address %}
    <img src="{{ address|e('html_attr') }}">
{% endfor %}
```

You can print variables (and other expressions) by putting them into double curly braces.